# Understanding this program which prints a sentence in reverse but keeps the words unchanged

Tags: arrays, c, loops, for-loop

I don't quite understand this program. I don't understand what is happening in the for loop. Can someone explain to me in simple words. And the site also didn't explain it well-enough. This is the link to the site. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-words-string-reverse-order/

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 
void printReverse(char str[])
{
    int length = strlen(str);
    FILE *fptr;
    if((fptr=fopen("Question1.txt","w"))==NULL)
    {
        printf("Invalid file");
        exit(0);
    }


    int i;
    for (i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (str[i] == ' ') 
        {
 
            str[i] = '\0';
 
            printf("%s ", &(str[i]) + 1);
            fprintf(fptr,"%s ", &(str[i]) + 1);
        }
    }

    fprintf(fptr,"%s",str);
    printf("%s.", str);

    fclose(fptr);
}

int main()
{
    char str[1000];
    //clrscr();

    printf("Enter string: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]s", str);

    printReverse(str);

    //getch();
    return 0;
}
```

In the `for` loop, why put `&(str[i])+1`? And also in `printf("%s.", str)`--this only has the first word; how?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us what difficulties you have in understanding the explanation on the linked web page. The linked page even contains C code with explanatory comments.

Comment: The article you link explains it in very simple terms. I don't think anybody here could make it simpler than that. It loops from the end of the string towards the beginning looking for space characters. If it finds a space it first modified the string by replacing the space with the end of string marker then prints the word it just looped over. Repeat. After the loop exits it prints the first word (as may be no space before the first word). Note it prints to both stdout and a file.

Comment: Made the necessary changes @bodo

Comment: `this only has the first word how?` because the first space character `' '` was replaced with a null terminator `'\0'`. When you print a c-string the operation ends at the first null terminator

Comment: Oh okay okay. Thank you so much. @drescherjm

Comment: @MartinYork thank you for explaning again. I just wasn't able to understand from that site I am not sure why, probably because I am just tried or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, let's see if I can help. I'll go through the code carefully.

I suspect you already understand this. It's just a method call.

```
void printReverse(char str[])
{
```

`strlen` is a standard method that returns the length of a null-terminated string. That means that str might contain Hello (5 characters), but there's one more byte with a 0 in it, which is how C has always marked the end of the string. In this case, str itself takes 6 bytes, but length will be 5.

```
    int length = strlen(str);
```

This is how you open a file in C. C++ has better ways. The file is written for writing.

```
    FILE *fptr;
    if((fptr=fopen("Question1.txt","w"))==NULL)
    {
        printf("Invalid file");
        exit(0);
    }
```

Here's your for-loop. Let's assume str contains `Hello`, so length is 5, but the indexes into string are `str[0..4]`. C uses the index as "offset from the beginning", so the first element is 0, not 1. Thus, when this loop starts, `str[i]` == `o` (using `Hello` as our example string). We then loop, decrementing `i` each time. Once `i` goes below 0, the loop ends.

```
    int i;
    for (i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
```

Okay, remember we're printing the words in normal order, but the words themselves are in reverse order. So this looks for a space -- between words. So if we use `Hello there` as our input text, this if-statement is true when `i` is pointing to the space between the two words.

Now here's the trick. Remember what I said earlier about null-terminated strings? What this does is to step on that space and replace it with a 0. That makes the rest of this magic work.

```
        if (str[i] == ' ') 
        {
 
            str[i] = '\0';
```

And here's the magic. Now, this is a strange way to do it. I would have done it with `&str[i+1]`, but this works. What this is doing is saying "Print the string that begins after the space we just clobbered." We do it to the terminal and the file.

```
            printf("%s ", &(str[i]) + 1);
            fprintf(fptr,"%s ", &(str[i]) + 1);
        }
    }
```

This writes the produced rearranged string to the file that was opened as well as to your terminal then makes sure the file is closed.

```
    fprintf(fptr,"%s",str);
    printf("%s.", str);

    fclose(fptr);
}
```

This all works because we step on the spaces with a zero. For `Hello world`, we:

1. Start from the tail
2. Find the space and stick a zero in it
3. Print `world`
4. Keep backing up to the end of the data.
5. Drop out of the for-loop and print whatever is left: `Hello`

Comment: Thank you so so much. I should have made myself a little clearly by mentioning that I didn't understand the ```&(str[i]) + 1``` part. And you are saying that ```&str[i+1]``` is the same as this ```&str[i]+1```? How? And why put a & there? Doesn't a string point to it's own address?

Comment: @SuburbanBourbon, Google "pointer arithmetic" for help. In this case adding one to the index or the ptr results in the same thing only because the pointer points to a size 1 (1 byte) piece of data, namely, a char. If it pointed to a 4 byte piece of data, for instance, adding one to the pointer would be the same as incrementing the index by 4, which would be very different.

Comment: @GabrielStaples thank you for telling me that. I'll look into it

Comment: @GabrielStaples Just one more thing why put &? Doesn't a string array point to it's own address or something like that please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: `str` by itself is a pointer--ie: the address to the first char in the string. `str[0]`, however is NOT a pointer. It is the actual character at the start of the string. `&str[0]` is a pointer--the address of this char, which, since it is at index `0`, is the same as `str` since they both point to the first char of the string. So, to get a pointer to a new string somewhere within the existing string, you first obtain the desired char with `str[i]`, then take the address of that to get a pointer to that location.

Comment: Thank you again @GabrielStaples

Answer (score 1):

**Answer to your specific questions**

> In the for loop why put? `&(str[i])+1`?

`&str[i]` is the address of the character at index `i` where a space has been replaced with a NUL character. With `+1` you get the address of the character after it, i.e. the beginning of the word that follows the space that was just replaced. (In case of double spaces this would result in an empty string.)

> And also in `printf("%s.", str);` this only has the first word how?

Assuming the first word is not preceded by a space, the loop will not print it.

This `printf("%s.", str);` will print the string from the beginning until the first NUL character that replaces a former space character, hence resulting in the first word.

**Additional question from comment**

> So... for example if I input `Hello World` does the `W` in that get the index 0?

The `W` is at index 6. (`H` is 0, `e` is 1 etc.)

When `i` has been counted down to 5, the space at this position will be replaced with a NUL (`'\0'`) character, and it will print the remaining string from the `W` up to the end of the string which is also marked by a NUL character. (As defined by the C standard.)

> And what if the character is not a NULL character? Then it won't go execute if right? It'll just increment i again till it encounters another NULL right?

I don't fully understand these questions. In case there was no NUL character at the end of the string `printf` would read past the end of the string leading to undefined behavior.

In case of an input string `Hello World and Universe", all spaces after` World`would have been replaced with NUL characters before, so when the program reaches the position of the space before`World`, the string will be

```
Hello World\0and\0Universe\0
```

before the replacement and

```
Hello\0World\0and\0Universe\0
```

after the replacement.